# Scala - No TypeTag Available Exception when using case class to try to get TypeTag?

Tags: scala, reflection, types

I'm looking at the scala reflect API and I'm getting lots of exceptions.

Doc reference:
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html

How do I get the typetag from a generic?

```
  def getChildSettings[T: ru.TypeTag](path: String, settingsParameterObject: T) = {

    import scala.reflect.runtime.{ currentMirror => m }

    val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val classC = ru.typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass
}
```

I get an exception:

```
No TypeTag available for ParameterObject.type
```

Even a very simple example doesn't seem to work (edit yes it does in the repl)

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

def getTypeTag[T: ru.TypeTag](obj: T) = ru.typeTag[T]

case class ParameterObject(stringType: String, optionType: Option[String])

getTypeTag(ParameterObject)
```

I'm guessing it's something about how I'm invoking the method.

Comment: Hum, just pasting your simple example in the REPL (and removing `settings.`) works for me on 2.10.1. Could you be missing scala-reflect on your classpath?

Comment: Brutal ! You're right it does work in the repl. I figured it out - the case classes cannot be nested!! I had the case class defined inside a test case and that's what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I finally found out what the issue was. 
The case classes must be defined top level - they cannot be nested.
Something like this would fail.

```
class Foo {
  describe("getSettings") {
    case class ParameterObject(foo: String)
    settings.getTypeTag(path, ParameterObject)
  }
}

class Clazzy {
      def getTypeTag[T: TypeTag](obj: T) = ru.typeTag[T]
}
```

Comment: Everybody who reads this, see also Yaroslav's answer. You can _either_ move all your classes to top level and continue using `typeOf`/`TypeTag` _or_ keep them where they are and use `weakTypeOf`/`WeakTypeTag` instead. (In cases where both functions work, they produce the same output.)

Comment: Does this mean we cannot write a simple scala script as shown in your original post and make it run?

Comment: for top level case class thing, it applies when writing unit tests too; the case class needs to be outside of the tests.

Answer (score 16):

Please declare Case class before you run main class

Example

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Long)

def main(args: Array[String]) {
   ...
    val people = sc.textFile("C:\\winutils\\people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
```

Answer (score 9):

If you need type tags for nested classes, you may use WeakTypeTag. I don't know why, but [that's intentionally](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6649).

Answer (score 4):

Add this code in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This comment at the end of a thread - is what worked for me!

Comment: Yup, also helped me in the context of Apache Spark.

Comment: Not recommanded. scala-reflect is part of the Scala compiler and should match the version of Scala, or it'll introduce dependency of another scala-library.

Comment: I am using different versions of the scala that leads to this error.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `TypeTag` at compile time, because that is the way to work around erasure:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => m, universe => ru}

def getChildSettings[T: TypeTag](path: String, settingsParameterObject: T) = {
  val tpe    = ru.typeOf[T]
  // val classC = tpe.typeSymbol.asClass
  val ctor   = tpe.declaration(ru.nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
  ...
}
```

The [Scala Documentation Overview for Reflection](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) gives an example of getting and invoking a constructor.

Comment: Ah okay. I see. I have to go [T: ru.TypeTag] actually - thanks man - I couldn't see what I was missing.

Comment: I think it's how I'm invoking the methdod.

Comment: I updated the question - let me know if that helps clarify where my problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I figured it out - the case classes can't be nested - they have to be top level or that exception is thrown.