# Why does scala treat locally defined classes differently to classes in outer scopes?

Tags: scala

What does the compiler see differently in each class declaration below that causes typeOf to behave differently. (i.e. what's the property of the class declaration that causes it to fail).

```
import org.junit.Test
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._


case class Person1(name: String)
class ReflectTest {

  case class Person2(name: String)

  @Test
  def constructorTest(): Unit = {

    case class Person3(name: String)

    typeOf[Person1]  // Yep
    typeOf[Person2]  // No problem
    typeOf[Person3]  // No typetag information available :(
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala - No TypeTag Available Exception when using case class to try to get TypeTag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988558/scala-no-typetag-available-exception-when-using-case-class-to-try-to-get-typet)

Comment: already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988558/scala-no-typetag-available-exception-when-using-case-class-to-try-to-get-typet)

Comment: 1) My question's a little different: *what does the compiler see* that causes this effect (not -- please fix my syntax error).
2) The referenced question doesn't even provide enough information to answer the problem that author accepted as an self-answer.

Comment: [SI-6649](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6649) (linked from the linked answer) says that you cannot create a type tag for a local class, and `Person3` is a local class.

Comment: SI-6649 also doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, it does. `Person3` is a local class. SI-6649 specifically says you cannot have a type tag for a local class. Therefore `typeOf` will not work for it.

Comment: Yes! That's clear from my original question. What's different about the local class as far as TypeTag is concerned?

Comment: The compiler won't generate a `TypeTag` for it. That's it. It's not a satisfying answer, but I doubt you'll get much more.

Comment: I doubt very much that that's the whole story.

Comment: One possibility is simply that the `TypeTag` would allow you to access the type outside the method (e.g. if it was part of the return value) which goes against the point of a local class (so does `getClass`, but Scala can't do anything about that). However, I think the question is more likely to be answered on scala-users Google group rather than here.

Comment: It also does answer the question "what does the compiler see" because the error message is clear: once the compiler sees the class is local, it stops there. It doesn't answer why the compiler is implemented like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a free type. And you can't refer to it with a prefix.

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> class C { class D }
defined class C

scala> val c = new C
c: C = C@29626d54

scala> val x = { final class X ; weakTypeTag[X] }
x: reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag[_ <: AnyRef] = WeakTypeTag[X]

scala> val t = typeTag[C]
t: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[C] = TypeTag[C]

scala> val w = typeTag[c.D]
w: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[c.D] = TypeTag[c.D]

scala> val v = typeTag[C#D]
v: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[C#D] = TypeTag[C#D]

scala> (t.tpe.typeSymbol, t.tpe.typeSymbol.isStatic)
res1: (reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol, Boolean) = (class C,true)

scala> (x.tpe.typeSymbol, x.tpe.typeSymbol.isStatic)
res2: (reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol, Boolean) = (free type X,false)

scala> (w.tpe.typeSymbol, w.tpe.typeSymbol.isStatic)
res3: (reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol, Boolean) = (class D,false)

scala> (v.tpe.typeSymbol, v.tpe.typeSymbol.isStatic)
res4: (reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol, Boolean) = (class D,false)

scala> reflect.runtime.universe.internal.asFreeType(x.tpe.typeSymbol)
res5: reflect.runtime.universe.FreeTypeSymbol = free type X
```

Other things you can't do with local classes, as [mentioned in the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#statements):

```
scala> val x = { private class X ; weakTypeTag[X] }
<console>:1: error: illegal start of statement (no modifiers allowed here)
val x = { private class X ; weakTypeTag[X] }
          ^

scala> import c.D
import c.D
```

I'd look more but it's late and my REPL broke...

```
scala> val y = { final class X { class Y } ; val x = new X ; import x.Y ; weakTypeTag[Y] } 
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: x.type
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$adaptToNewRunMap$.adaptToNewRun(TypeMaps.scala:1106)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$adaptToNewRunMap$.apply(TypeMaps.scala:1150)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$adaptToNewRunMap$.apply(TypeMaps.scala:1079)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$adaptToNewRunMap$.apply(TypeMaps.scala:1148)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$TypeMap.mapOver(TypeMaps.scala:162)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$adaptToNewRunMap$.apply(TypeMaps.scala:1197)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$adaptToNewRunMap$.apply(TypeMaps.scala:1171)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.adaptInfos(Symbols.scala:1629)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.rawInfo(Symbols.scala:1581)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.isStale(Typers.scala:504)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.reallyExists(Typers.scala:496)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectInternal$1(Typers.scala:4712)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelect$1(Typers.scala:4676)
```