# The difference between running a scala script directly vs through a scala shell

Tags: scala, reflection

I ran into the "No TypeTag available for" error when running a simple script:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru} 
case class Person(name: String)
val classPerson = ru.typeOf[Person].typeSymbol.asClass
```

The script is an example from [Scala Reflection Doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html.). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988558/scala-no-typetag-available-exception-when-using-case-class-to-try-to-get-typet) post, the error is caused by the fact that the case class is not defined at the top level. I know scala automatically compiles a scala script into a class before running it, thus making the case class a internally defined class, but the same script would work if it is run in a scala shell. So what is the difference between running a scala script and running the same script through the scala shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is discrepancy between the Scala Shell and a Scala program in this case.  It still wouldn't work if the case class isn't defined "top-level" in the shell:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru} 
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>ru}

scala> case class Something(name: String)
defined class Something

scala> ru.typeOf[Something].typeSymbol.asClass
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassSymbol = class Something

scala> { case class Something(name: String); ru.typeOf[Something].typeSymbol.asClass }

<console>:16: error: No TypeTag available for Something
    { case class Something(name: String); ru.typeOf[Something].typeSymbol.asClass }
                                                  ^
```

[EDIT] Response to comments appended below:

It'll work in a program too as long as the case class is defined "top-level".  The following code will compile and output the class name:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru} 

case class Something(name: String)

object MyReflection extends App {
  println ("My case class: " + ru.typeOf[Something].typeSymbol.asClass)
}
```

Comment: To clarify my question, why defining case class Something(name: String) without enclosing them in {} would work in a scala shell, but the same code does not work in a scala script?

Comment: Please see my response in the expanded answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But you wrote a scala program, not a scala script. I understand why this program would work, but I do not understand why the three-line script shown in the main question does not work.

Comment: Ahh, my bad, I thought you were comparing behavior between shell and programs.  I haven't used Scala scripts much, but I expect the Scala interpreter would wrap the case class inside a wrapper class , making it no longer top-level – as can be revealed if you try run `scalac` with `-Ydebug` `-Xscript` options against the script file, you should see something like `No TypeTag available for $anon.this.Something`.

Comment: I copied the three liner to a file named `test.scala` and then ran `scalac -Ydebug -Xscript test.scala test.scala` and was able to replicate your results. So this shows that when running scripts, the classes defined in the script are wrapped in another wrapper class (`$anon` in this case) - but when running the same script through the scala shell, those classes are each compiled on the fly as a top-level class. Do you think this is what is going on?

Comment: Yes, in Scala shell, things get interpreted one after another (unless you place them within a code block), hence the case class within your three-liner will be treated as top-level.