# spark kafkastream to cassandra in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to insert Kafka-stream Json data into my Cassandra using Scala, but unfortunately getting stuck. My Code is :-

```
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
val records = kafkaStream.map(_._2)
val collection = records.flatMap(_.split(",")).map(s => event(s(0).toString, s(1).toString))
case class event(vehicleid: String, vehicletype: String)
collection.foreachRDD(x => println(x))
collection.saveToCassandra("traffickeyspace", "test", SomeColumns("vehicleid", "vehicletype"))
```

The Error I'm getting is :-

```
not enough arguments for method saveToCassandra: (implicit connector: com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector, implicit rwf: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RowWriterFactory[event])Unit. Unspecified value parameter rwf. kafkatesting.scala  /SparkRedis/src/com/spark/test  line 48 Scala Problem
```

and other error is :-

```
could not find implicit value for parameter rwf: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RowWriterFactory[event]    kafkatesting.scala  /SparkRedis/src/com/spark/test  line 48 Scala Problem
```

My JSON record from producer is :-

```
{"vehicleId":"3a92516d-58a7-478e-9cff-baafd98764a3","vehicleType":"Small Truck","routeId":"Route-37","longitude":"-95.30818","latitude":"33.265877","timestamp":"2018-03-28 06:21:47","speed":58.0,"fuelLevel":25.0}
```

Comment: Hi @Jacek, I'm new to Spark. I just followed online samples to build this code. Can you please provide me example of Spark Structured Streaming for this code?

Comment: Read the official [Structured Streaming Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually cannot declare your case class where you have. Case classes have to be defined at the top level scope to get the `TypeTag` they need. Look here for more details: [Scala - No TypeTag Available Exception when using case class to try to get TypeTag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988558/scala-no-typetag-available-exception-when-using-case-class-to-try-to-get-typet)

So move your case class to the top level scope of the file you are in. This way it gets it `TypeTag`, allowing it to get its `ColumnMapper` which allows it to pick up its `implicit RowWriterFactor`

Comment: Hi @soote, your advice worked. Thanks. I declared my case class outside object and it worked but now , there is more concern . My cassandra column is filled like this :-

vehicleid                                           | vehicletype
 {"vehicleId":"2d0ac015-5a54-4db1-92cb-9a19ee90cd39" |         "vehicleType":"Bus"
 {"vehicleId":"6ef03426-689e-48a9-a576-cac5e0829955" |        "vehicleType":"Taxi"
 {"vehicleId":"c5b9846c-2992-4e4e-9e70-544599b3a140" | "vehicleType":"Private Car"

I want this the ID value and not the kye "vehicleID"  how to do this ?

Comment: @AdityaJain You need to look into the `from_json` function from the `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions` package.